# Android Scroll Thumb Disappears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am experiencing a very strange issue with my layout. I have an Activity with a content frame for my app's fragments. Inside one of my fragments I have a ListView with Fast Scroll enabled.

Now, the issue I am having is that the "scroll thumb" (for fasting scrolling) only works in the first fragment that my app shows, and only the first time that fragment is shown.

If I reload the first fragment the scroll thumb disappears. If I switch to a different fragment also containing a ListView with fast scroll, the scroll thumb also disappears.

However, if I reload the entire activity (i.e. close the app and open it again) the problem repeats. It only works once until I reopen my app.

The only partial workaround I've found so far is to use fastScrollAlwaysVisible, in this case the fast scroll is indeed always visible, but that is not the behavior I want. I only want the scroll to show when you scroll in the list.

The left image is the correct scroll behavior, which only works the first time. The right image is the incorrect scroll behavior, where the scroll thumb has disappeared and reverts back to normal scrolling.

Note: before the scroll thumb appears for a very short time when I change to a different fragment.

[image: Good Scroll]
[image: Bad Scroll]

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem and figured out that Fast Scroll Thumb disappears after the second setting of the android.app.ListActivity.setListAdapter(ListAdapter).
I fixed this by changing cursor of the new ListAdapter first to the empty cursor (having the same columns...) and then to the actual cursor using activity.getListAdapter()).changeCursor(cursor)

Please see the diff of this commit: 
https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/commit/685df904a6c62e656a627e4eb021034f2150ce8f

Please note that the Fast Scroll Thumb doesn't disappear when you don't change ListAdapter, but simply replaces old cursor with a new one using the call: activity.getListAdapter()).changeCursor(cursor);

Comment: It seems like the problem is related to the fact that I am using fragments. Since my fragment is being re-created I have to call setListAdapter again (since it's a new view and a new list). Also I'm not using a cursor, just a regular ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

I am now unable to reproduce the issue. I suspect it might have been fixed with the latest update of Android (4.4.3).